# Unix syntax for the grep command for only an ending character

Tags: unix

For the file `james`, when I run this command:

```
cat james | grep ["."]
```

I get only the lines that contain a dot.

How do I get only the lines that *end* with a dot?

Comment: FYI you don't need to call cat. Just `grep ["."] james` will work.

Comment: @squiguy: Yes, but it's not at all obvious *why* `grep ["."]` works. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find lines that end with a `.` character:

```
grep '\.$' james
```

Your `cat` command is [unnecessary](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html); `grep` is able to read the file itself, and doesn't need `cat` to do that job for it.

A `.` character by itself is special in regular expressions, matching any one character; you need to escape it with a `\` to match a literal `.` character.

And you need to enclose the whole regular expression in single quotes because the `\` and `$` characters are special to the shell. In a regular expression, `$` matches the end of a line. (You're dealing with some characters that are treated specially by the shell, and others that are treated specially by `grep`; the single quotes get the shell out of the way so you can control what `grep` sees.)

As for the square brackets you used in your question, that's another way to escape the `.`, but it's unusual. In a regular expression, `[abc]` matches a single character that's any of `a`, `b`, or `c`. `[.]` matches a single literal `.` character, since `.` loses its special meaning inside square brackets. The double quotes you used: `["."]` are unnecessary, since `.` isn't a shell metacharacter -- but square brackets *are* special to the shell, with a similar meaning to their meaning in a regular expression. So your

```
grep ["."]
```

is equivalent to

```
grep [.]
```

The shell would normally expand `[.]` to a list of every visible file name that contains the single character `.`. There's always such a file, namely the current directory `.` -- but the shell's `[]` expansion ignores files whose names start with `.`. So since there's nothing to expand `[.]` to, it's left alone, and `grep` sees `[.]` as an argument, which *just happens* to work, matching lines that contain a literal `.` character. (Using a different shell, or the same shell with different settings, could mess that up.)

Note that the shell doesn't (except in some limited contexts) deal with regular expressions; rather it uses file matching patterns, which are less powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$`, which signals the end of the line:

```
cat james | grep ["."]$
```

This also works:

```
cat james |grep "\.$"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression. This is what you need :

```
cat james | grep "\.$"
```

Look at grep manpage for more informations about regexp

Comment: The `-E` is not necessary; `"\.$"` isn't part of the *extended* regular expression syntax. And single quotes would be better than double quotes; `$` is a shell metacharacter. (The shell doesn't treat the `$` specially *in this case*.)

Comment: You dropped the `-E`, but you're still using double quotes and the unnecessary `cat`.